# Disable view of deleted posts

Tags: feature-request

Users with 10K reputation points have the privilege of seeing deleted posts. As far as I know, there is no way for a user with 10K points to turn off this "privilege". Wouldn't it be desirable to have a way to do that?

Comment: Are you asking for an option so that an individual with 10k+ rep can stop seeing all deleted posts, or an option which lets him selectively stop seeing deleted posts by a single other user?

Comment: @BESW The former is what I had in mind. I see that my wording was ambiguous. I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Deleted questions don't normally show up in searches, and deleted answers sort to the bottom of the list.  Is seeing them a problem somehow..?

Comment: @Izkata One question had a very long deleted answer that was annoying me. I don't know if it was the right thing to do, but I solved that problem by editing the deleted answer. Another problem with deleted answers is that, on my monitor, and with my eyes, it's not that easy to see that they are deleted.

Comment: @user14111 - editing a deleted answer to prevent it annoying you seems like vandalism at best.  I suggest that you roll that back.

Comment: @DarthSatan Sorry about the vandalism. You see, I was writing my own answer to the same question, and in the process of composing my answer I was scrolling back and forth between my draft and the question, and I was getting tired of scrolling past **15 pages** of deleted matter. So I replaced that list of every work of fiction published in *F&SF* between January 1989 and December 1991 with a line of text saying that anyone who wants to see that list should roll back to the earlier version. Following your suggestion, I have rolled back my edit. Mea maxima culpa.

Comment: @DarthSatan Say, aren't you supposed to be on the side of us evildoers?

Answer (score 5):

I think such a feature is unlikely to ever gain traction with the SE developers. As Richard’s answer explains, they’re fairly useful to most 10k users, and I think very few people would actually use it.

If you really want to hide all deleted answers, then add this snippet of CSS to your browser:

```
.deleted-answer {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Pretty much every browser has an option or plugin for injecting custom CSS; just Google around to find one that suits you.

> Another problem with deleted answers is that, on my monitor, and with my eyes, it's not that easy to see that they are deleted.

You can fix this with a different bit of CSS:

```
.deleted-answer {
    background-color: #ffaaaa !important;
}
```

This shows deleted answers in a fairly strong shade of reddish-pink. Here’s what it looks like:

[image]

Tweak the colour as appropriate for your monitor.

Comment: Thanks, but your computerese is Greek to me. Anyway, I didn't want to disable my view of deleted answers permanently; I wanted to be able to turn it off and on at will.

Comment: @user14111 Install Stylish (a web browser extension), use the first code block on the domain "stackexchange.com".  Then enable and disable Stylish to hide/show deleted posts.

Answer (score 3):

Even if such a feature existed, I'd be quite surprise if many high-rep users chose to activate it, not least because some deleted answers do actually contain some useful information.

Your own reasons for wanting it seem quite personal and esoteric:

- That there was a **single answer** that was annoying you
- That the colouration isn't terribly clear on deleted answers **on your monitor**

As such, it would seem far simpler to fix your *own* experience (by, for example using [this script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132134/hide-deleted-answer-content) that hides deleted answers and adjusting the contrast on your monitor) rather than globally implementing a feature for which there is no demand.